# CakePHP baseUrl issue

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

Earlier I had my `app/build` inside `/var/www/beta` and it was working fine. But when I moved the project from beta to `/var/www` I am getting issues.

When I add the `rewrite.script` I get the access to the controllers but no css or js.

I then uncommented this line in `Config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl',  env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

I now get all the css and js but I get missing controllers. I have to 
put index.php in the url.

> www.mydomain.com/index.php/login

Can't see what I am missing. 
I have already made changes from Allowoverride None to all in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Hope someone helps me solving this issue as this is driving me mad.

Comment: The config in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder is not loaded by default. It's just there for example purposes. The config should reside in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Unless you've mutilized your main Apache config to load the sites-available config, that's probably your problem right there. You may still need to run `a2ensite default` if the default config is not in the `sites-enabled` folder.

Comment: I made the changes in defualt file but was able to run a2enmod command.Gives an error "file already exists not tocuhing it"

Comment: in the above comment its *unable to run a2enmod command

Answer (score 0):

Did you empty app/tmp/cache/persistent (and app/tmp/cache/models possibly)?

Comment: After your reply i did but issue did not get resolved

Comment: You need to re-enable App.baseUrl, then try setting debug to 1 to see what happens...

Comment: I did this step also but still the issues is there

Comment: That is strange. Did you copy .htaccess files too?